# Postgtres query is not using index for column which is indexed

Tags: postgresql

Today I faced a strange issue. I have a big table in postgres (table T) which has many columns (col1..col100) and I have index I1 on (col2,col3,col4).

Now

```
explain select col2,col3 from T;
```

shows seq scan for the table, not using the index. I think it should be like Index only scan as we are selecting columns which are in index.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** -  [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

First of all read this and analyze. I think this may be helpful:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/why-postgres-wont-always-use-an-index

Answer (score 0):

If the SELECT returns more than approximately 5-10%(depends on configuration settings and the storage of the data as well. It's not a hard number) of all rows in the table, a sequential scan is much faster than an index scan.

Index scan requires several IO operations for each row (look up the row in the index, then retrieve the row from the heap). Sequential scan only requires a single IO for each row - or even less because a block (page) on the disk contains more than one row, so more than one row can be fetched with a single IO operation.

This is true for other DBMS as well - some optimizations as "index only scans" taken aside (but for a SELECT * it's highly unlikely such a DBMS would go for an "index only scan")